# Remove horizontal line from the headers of a page

Tags: header-footer

I am using the springer journal class svjour3 for my work. The class svjour3.cls has commands authorrunning and titlerunning to repeat the authour and title names for the journal at the header of the page. However it inserts a horizontal line underneath the entries which i want to remove. How can i achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are preparing an article for a journal, it might be a bad idea to modify the style of the publisher.

However, you may try to add `\def\runheadhook{}` after `\documentclass{svjour3}`.